# Lyapunov functions : why we don’t just use Newtonian mechanics?

Tags: classical-mechanics, stability-theory, lyapunov-functions

I am studying nonlinear control theory, and I wanted to ask a question about Lyapunov functions please.

So there is the Lyapunov theorem for stability of $\dot{x}=f(x)$ using Lyapunov functions, but the problem is that there are no formulas to determine the Lyapunov functions. Why we can not just study the stability of the point x in the phase space using potential energy ?

I saw some articles where they consider x as a charged particle in space with Lorenz force, but I mean, we can just write :
$$\ddot{x} = \frac{df}{dx}\dot{x}$$
and consider this formula as a : 1.acceleration = Forces
and then it becomes a study of stability of this point mass ? In this case we could directly use the potential energy of the mass from the right hand side (the forces) to find if it is stable or not no ? Of course i understand that we can not do this for any system since we need for example f to be differentiable, but I don’t understand why we do not just use this potential energy for Lyapunov function ?

Thank you in advance for your answers
Best regards

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: For stabilization we need dissipation and dissipation depends generally on velocities. Potential energy  knowledge is not sufficient.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I think I understand. When we say that the stable equilibrium point corresponds to the minima of potential energy, we are assuming that all the forces are conservative. In this case using potential energy as Lyapunov function works, but the idea of Lyapunov function is that we find a generalisation of potential energy to the case where there are dissipative  forces, is this true ?